# Database poorly designed

Tags: database, testing, architecture

I don't know if I can made this kind of question here so previously I apologize.

I work with a system that has a lot of dependencies and a poorly designed database. Now I have to make a decision and would like to hear some cases of you people.

That's the case: some part of the software was made without thinking in all cases of uses. Today I need to do severe changes like creating new relations on the database, refactoring all the classes and methods. That's what the theory says, but in pratice this will take a lot of days, will delay the version and the entire schedule. I have the option to keep the gambiarra (bad code that works) and make just the little changes that meets the new needs.

I know that each case is different, so I want to hear what would you do and if have you been through something similar.

Comment: no software can be made knowing all the ways a system can be used before hand

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to provide some advice with so little detail, however I think you need to make the stakeholders aware that what they are asking is going to be timely and costly.

That being said, try to break all this work into a set of workable changes (I understand you already have some user stories). Deliver these incrementally and prioritise them so that your stakeholders start getting value soon.

Probably running a workshop with them to understand which ones are the most important for them and weigh them against the effort and risk of implementation is a good way to align everyone on the same page.

Good luck, sounds like you are going to need it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common situation. You don't provide any specific details, so it's hard to answer other than in general terms.

There's always a trade-off between getting the job done, worrying about the future, and technical debt.

Worrying about the future - features you think you'll need in a future release - is a abad idea. "I'll just put this in right now, and then it will make that next release a bit easier" - every single time, that "just in case" bit of code needs love and attention, and every single time, it's not quite right when the time comes. So, I don't recommend building support for future use cases. It slows you down, and you tend to guess wrong about what you need later on anyway. In Agile, they use the YAGNI acronym - "You ain't gonna need it". Very specifically in reply to your question - I do not think code or design that doesn't support future use cases is "bad".

However, you should really, really worry about technical debt. Is your code modular, covered by decent test cases, readable, not too complex? One aspect of quality is "how easy is it to extend this?". That's a very different question - and code that's hard to extend *is* bad code.

If you find yourself in that situation, you may want to introduce your company to the concept of [technical debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt). Sometimes, it's a good decision to take on technical debt - and I've never worked on a project that didn't have some degree of this. But it's a business question, not a technical question. It boils down to "how much future money do you want to spend maintaining or extending this feature in return for getting this out the door sooner?". If this is the very last release, the answer is probably "a lot". If this is the very first in a long release plan, the answer is probably "not very much".